# Items without group in LongListSelector

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding, longlistselector

I want to add items through binding to LongListSelector.These items are not supposed to be in a group and they should be on the top of the list. Other items are in groups. Is any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LongListSelector only supports having items in a group, or not in a group. You should consider having a seperate List with your header items in the LongListSelector's `HeaderTemplate`.